# Print CSS page break

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to fix this in **Print CSS**

[image]

Comment: What browser(s)? Possible duplicate if this is just IE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223860/how-do-i-keep-a-td-element-from-appearing-across-multiple-pages-when-printed-f

Answer (score 2):

There is a CSS call for `page-break`. Use this to get the effect you want.

```
table { 
    page-break-inside:auto 
}
tr
{ 
    page-break-inside:avoid; 
    page-break-after:auto 
}
```

- [MDN - Page Break Inside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside)
- [MDN - Page Break After](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after)